# Unexpected unknown type in the empty function call

Tags: typescript

Why in this situation "a" variable type - unknown, while absence of value is an undefined type?

```
function action<T>(value?: T): T | undefined {
    return value;
}

let a = action();
```

Comment: Because there's no way to infer `T`, the default is `unknown`.

Comment: I understand you, but it's strange in this case that default is not an undefined.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#generic-type-parameters-are-implicitly-constrained-to-unknown

Comment: Use a default if you want to specify a default if no inference can be made: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQ2vMAeAKogvI8AEwFNgYxjCA+ACgDdkAbEYgfgC5EsBKTnAHwJgSZCoUQBvAFCJZiAE7EoIeUgbNiAbikBfKVMZKUeFGgQ1umoA

Answer (score 1):

Use a default value for your generic type.

```
function action<T = undefined>(value?: T): T | undefined {
    return value;
}

let a = action(); //undefined
let b = action(3); //number
```